# googlesheet addon x-frame-options

Tags: google-apps-script, x-frame-options

I wrote a googlesheets app script add-on which works fine in normal mode (invoked from docs.google.com in address bar). I am trying to use it as well in iframe embedded mode inside my web app but I am getting an set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' even though I call 
 setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL) while creating the sidebar. The spreadsheet opens correctly, the addon menu loads as well, but opening the sidebar fails. What am I missing?

```
function openSidebar_(file) {
        var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file).evaluate()
                .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
                .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
                .setTitle('Wizard v'+getApiVersion())
                .setWidth(300);

        SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
                .showSidebar(html);
}
```